# Fill a jQuery query with words from external file

Tags: jquery

I use [a jQuery plugin to highlight](http://bartaz.github.io/sandbox.js/jquery.highlight.html) certain words inside a div.

I managed to make it work, no problem. My question is: how to fill the list of words to highlight with words from a file?

So I have this line of code:
`$('.textsection').highlight(["lorem", "non", "lectus"]);` that will hightlight "lorem", "non" and "lectus" from the text on the page. It works fine.

Instead of filling the words in the query, one by one, because I have hundreds of them, I'd like to tell jQuery to go take the list of words in a .txt file where each word is on one specific line, like:

```
lorem
non
lectus
```

Basically the result I'm searching for is something like `$('body').highlight(["wordslist.txt"]);` (which obviously won't work, but you get it).

How can I do that? How to properly give the .txt file to crawl to jQuery?

Thank you :)

P.S.: I'm trying to add "Hi", but doesn't work :(

Comment: use a js file instead of a txt file.

Comment: `$('body').highlight([wordslist.js]);` would work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest way would be to encode the words in a file using JSON and then use [$.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) to grab it from the server. Of course, since it's Javascript, it's preferred to do this asynchronously.

For example, say you have `["lorem", "non", "lectus"]` inside a text file called *data.json*. You would load it like this:

```
$.getJSON("data.json", function(data) {
    $('.textsection').highlight(data);
});
```

Comment: Event by trying in a PHP environment with WAMP, this doesn't work. I tried it both inside and outside a `$(document).ready(function()` Am I missing something? I am absolutely not confident with JSON, I know nothing about it :)

Comment: Is your data.json file in the correct directory? It should be in the same directory as the .html file. Check the Javascript console and see if there are any errors there.

Comment: Well it's a .php file, but yes, it's in the same directory. I'm working on localhost, if it ever matters. You say "encode in JSON", what do you mean exactly? Is listing each word on a separate line is enough, or data.json must actually contain some code? If some code is required, how can I do that?

Comment: I manage to make it work if, in data.json, I write `["lorem", "non", "lectus"]`. What am I missing to make it work without having to add all double quotes around words and removed all the line breaks?

Comment: You can't make it work without it - the [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) syntax requires all strings to be inside double quotes. The line breaks are probably optional though. You can try using a tool such as the [JSON editor](http://jsoneditoronline.org/?json=[%22lorem%22,%20%22non%22,%20%22lectus%22]) to help you generate a proper JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this  :

```
$.get( "wordslist.txt", function( data ) {
    var arr= data.split("\n");
    $('body').highlight(arr);
});
```

Comment: It's close to work, but it doesn't. When I do a document.write() to see what `data.split("\n")` returns, it's something like: `lorem ,non ,lectus` where it must return `"lorem", "non", "lectus"` (with double quote marks around each word)

Comment: Actually, even by shortening the list of words considerably to test, it doesn't work. In wordslist.txt I finish with `["lorem", "non", "lectus"]` directly written like this in the file, with `$.get( "badwords.txt", function( data ) { $('body').highlight(data); });` as code, it doesn't work.